# Galilean invariance of Schrödinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, gauge-invariance, galilean-relativity

I'm trying to prove that if $\psi (\mathbf r, t)$ satisfies
$$
i\hbar \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}(\mathbf r, t) = 
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left( \nabla-\frac{iq}{\hbar} \mathbf A \right)^2\psi(\mathbf r, t)
+ q\phi(\mathbf r, t)\psi(\mathbf r, t), \tag{1}
$$

then so does $\psi'(\mathbf r, t) := e^{i(m\mathbf{v\cdot r}-m\mathbf v^2t/2)/\hbar}\psi(\mathbf r - \mathbf vt, t)$ with $\mathbf A$ replaced with $\mathbf A'$ and $\phi$ replaved with $\phi'$, where $\mathbf A'(\mathbf r, t) := \mathbf A(\mathbf r - \mathbf vt, t)$ and $\phi'(\mathbf r, t):=\phi(\mathbf r-\mathbf vt, t)$. (Note that this is an *active* transformation.)

Everything is falling into place except just one term $2q\mathbf{v\cdot A'}\psi'$ that I get extra on the RHS after substituting $\psi'$ in place of $\psi$ in the original equation. I've checked my computaion three times already.

So any help?

---

**Edit:**

I did the following computation. First, I showed that for $\tilde{\psi}(\mathbf r, t) := \psi(\mathbf r -\mathbf vt, t)$,
$$
 i\hbar \frac{\partial\tilde\psi}{\partial t}(\mathbf r, t) = 
 -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left( \nabla - i\frac{q}{\hbar} \mathbf A' \right)^2 \tilde{\psi} (\mathbf r, t)
 + q\phi'(\mathbf r, t)\tilde{\psi}(\mathbf r, t)
 - i\hbar \mathbf v\cdot\nabla\tilde{\psi}(\mathbf r, t).\tag{2}
 $$

This is also what Merzbacher gets.
Now, putting $\tilde\psi = \mathfrak e\psi'$ *(I define $\mathfrak e(\mathbf r, t) := e^{i(m\mathbf{v\cdot r}-m\mathbf v^2t/2)/\hbar}$; everything from now on is evaluated at $(\mathbf r, t)$)*, I get
\begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial\tilde\psi}{\partial t} &= 
  \mathfrak e \left( \frac{\partial\psi'}{\partial t} 
  + \frac{im\mathbf v^2}{2\hbar} \psi' \right);
  \\
  \nabla\tilde\psi &=
  \mathfrak e \left( \nabla\psi' 
  -\frac{im\mathbf v}{\hbar} \psi' \right);
  \\
  \nabla^2 \tilde \psi &=
  \mathfrak e \left( -\frac{m^2\mathbf v^2}{\hbar^2}\psi'
  - \frac{2im}{\hbar} \mathbf v\cdot \nabla\psi'
   +\nabla^2 \psi' \right);\text{ and,}
  \\
  \nabla\cdot\mathbf A'\tilde\psi + 2\mathbf A'\cdot\nabla\tilde\psi &=
  \mathfrak e \left( \nabla\cdot\psi' 
  - \frac{2im}{\hbar} \mathbf v\cdot \mathbf A'\psi'
  + 2\mathbf A'\cdot \nabla\psi' \right).
  \\
 \end{align*}

Now, expanding $(2)$ and substituting by above equations, I get $(1)$ except that there is an extra term of $2q\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf A'\psi'$ also on the RHS.

---

### I demand to know why this question is being voted to close even if it is still unresolved!

Comment: Did you change the derivatives appropriately?

Comment: Yes, I did do that.

Comment: I think that checking computation is off topic here... still, you have to post more details about your computation.

Comment: @Vadim I've posted the details of my computation now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change of wavefunction due to relativistic speed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/405778/change-of-wavefunction-due-to-relativistic-speed)

Comment: @KFGauss No, that does **not** answer my question. There the highest-voted answer just mentions that the Galilean invariance holds. But I ask about the specific computation/proof.

Answer (score 0):

The Schrödinger equation is **not** Galilei covariant, even in the absence of electromagnetic fields. There is a symmetry group, the Schrödinger group, that describes the symmetry of the Schrödinger equation.  One reason for the Galilei non covariance is that the rest energy of matter is not included. For example, the Schrödinger equation for the hydrogen atom does not include the proton and electron rest energy. These can be included but in a [manuscript](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0403013) I argue that this is not sufficient. In the same [manuscript](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0403013)  I argue that its elements are not coordinate transformations as they depend on mass. Indeed the factor $$e^{i(m\mathbf{v\cdot r}-m\mathbf v^2t/2)/\hbar}$$ depends on mass and it **does not follow** from application of a Galilei transformation to the Schrödinger equation. It has to be postulated as part of an element of the Schrödinger group.  For a review of the Schrödinger group see ref 2 of my manuscript: H. Brown and P. R. Holland, Am. J. Phys. 67 (1999) 204 (behind a paywall).

Comment: The S equation *is* galilei covarint if $V(x) \to V(x-vt)$ and $\psi(x,t)\to e^{i(mx-mv^2t/2)}\psi(x-vt,t)$.  (which is the phase  the OP has in his question)This is a homework exercise in Baym's QM. The extra phase comes precisely from the Lorentz transofrm of the $e^{-imc^2t}$ that is pulled out of the invariant KG equation to make the S equation. See also my answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/405778/change-of-wavefunction-due-to-relativistic-speed/591230#591230